# FrameLayout inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml

I have two layouts one that is just going to be a background and another that is going to be in the center of it an take up around half of the screen. I have the code that I thought would do that however the view that I am including takes up the whole screen when the app runs and I cant figure out why that is happening.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<include
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    layout="@layout/activity_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

second xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#00000000" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frmPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgShoot"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:background="@drawable/aperture_closing" />
```

Comment: on which device r u testing this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using weights.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify any attribute other than `layout` on the `<include>` tag, since it will be replaced entirely by the root element of the layout you're including and they will be dropped. Also, you don't need a `RelativeLayout` to center a child. It's better to use a FrameLayout for performance reasons.

**Parent**:

```
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <include layout="@layout/activity_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Children**:

```
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="500dp"
  android:layout_height="500dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:background="#00000000">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frmPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
  </FrameLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgShoot"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:background="@drawable/aperture_closing"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note that if the parent `FrameLayout` doesn't contain any views other than the `<include>` tag, you can safely skip the parent layout and just use the children layout directly. Every activity already has a FrameLayout at its root.